# How to display website in windows phone app?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I am using below code

```
<phone:WebBrowser source="http:example.com"/>
```

this is the only code inside grid. But the app is crashing. What could be the issue?

Comment: webBrowser1.Source = new Uri("http://www.example.com", UriKind.Absolute);

Comment: I want to write only xaml, with NO C#, any way to do so.

Comment: try this its working <WebView x:Name="myWebView"
                     Height="650"
                     Source="http://google.com/" />

Comment: its working?@Vikash Ranjan Jha

Comment: Its not working may be because I have Windows Phone 7 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
<StackPanel>
        <WebView x:Name="myWebView"
                 Height="650"
                 Source="http://google.com/" />

</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <StackPanel>
            <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="wbBrwsrUI" Source="http://www.google.com/"/>
 </StackPanel>

or 

wbBrwsrUI.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```